# Ways for transmitting data using GNU Radio and soundcards

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am working on a Free-Space-Optics transceiver that uses the soundcard of a computer, a LED, a photodiode and a lens to transmit data over the air. At the moment I am trying to connect two transceivers with the help of GNU Radio. The GNU Radio tutorials and examples that I know of, all cover USB radio devices.

I already experimented with software called Minimodem which uses Audio Frequency Shift Keying for data transmission over the soundcard. GNU Radio offers a lot of useful blocks like Automatic Gain Control (helpful for changing signals due to light and weather conditions) etc., which is the reason I would like to use it for my experiments.

I understand that using the soundcard as the interface is a limiting factor for the achievable data rate.

I would appreciate advice of how to setup a reasonable flow graph in GNU Radio companion that enables a data transmission between the soundcards of two computers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need two out-of-tree modules for your soundcard in the Gnuradio. one sink(for transmitter) and one source(for receiver). If you already have some code that can send samples to your sound card, just create an oot module and put it in that module. if not, then write a C++ or Python code that can do this.